# Spelling Beelzebub

Tags: word, english

I've recently been banished to a land of eternal torment. Nevertheless, the first thing I do each morning is still to solve the New York Times Spelling Bee. Unfortunately, here they don't give out the letters. I've managed to get a few words through trial and error. Can you help me figure out which letter each color represents so I can get to Queen Beelzebub?
[image: Spelling Beelzebub]
Words found in alphabetical order:

1. ORYP
2. OPTOYTRBPGOPT
3. GRPPOY
4. GRYBTBGO

(Y=yellow, B=blue, P=purple, G=green, O=orange, T=teal, R=red)

Comment: So you are supposed to find what letters correspond to each color?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the question to make that more clear, thanks! @Duck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The words you've found are:

> EARN, ENTERTAINMENT, MANNER, and MARITIME.

So the colors are:

> red = A, orange = E, yellow = R, green = M, teal = T, blue = I, purple = N.

Comment: That was quick! Waiting on the time out to mark as accepted :)

Comment: If you know how to ask a computer it's quite easy to find matching words. `grep -i '^(.)(.)(.)\1(.)\3..\2.\1\2\3$' /usr/share/dict/words`, but that may not be the strategy used here.

Answer (score 4):

Words:

> Earn
>  Entertainment
>  Manner
>  Maritime

Colours:

> Yellow is "R"
>  Blue is "I"
>  Purple is "N"
>  Green is "M"
>  Orange is "E"
>  Teal is "T"
>  Red is "A"

Found this without writing a program or searching existing databases. Structure of the longest word provided the key after only a few minutes.